# Can we get a consistent green, please?

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

I just checked my profile page and found this:

[image]

Can we please have the accepted-answer score background and the reputation indicator (and privilege bar) in the same shade of green?

Comment: I like the blue actually. Can we get it blue?

Comment: wait that's supposed to be blue? ... Either way, consistency!

Comment: it's actually network-wise issue with profile. however, i will update a little that greenish-blueish color in upcoming release so it's more obvious it's green.